# Spring configuration properties recursive type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a configuration properties class that has a recursive class, structured similarly to a linked list. I'm using Spring boot 2.0.6.RELEASE, and the class is being autowired using `@EnableConfigurationProperties({EnginealConfig.class})`.

The issue I am having is that only one the first level will be bound to the Test object, `x.test` will never get set.

Using the following application.properties file:

```
engineal.x.value: "Test1"
engineal.x.test.value: "Test2"
engineal.x.test.test.value: "Test3"
```

And the following configuration properties class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "engineal")
public class EnginealConfig {

    static class Test {

        private String value;
        private Test test;

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Test getTest() {
            return test;
        }

        public void setTest(Test test) {
            this.test = test;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Test{" +
                    "value='" + value + '\'' +
                    ", test=" + test +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    private Test x;

    public Test getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(Test x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EnginealConfig{" +
                "x=" + x +
                '}';
    }
}
```

the object will print `EnginealConfig{x=Test{value='Test1', test=null}}`. Unfortunately the recursion is not working.

After messing around trying different things to get this to work, I tried changing EnginealConfig#Test.test from `private Test test;` to `private List<Test> test;`, along with the getters and setters. Then by using lists with one element, this recursion works.

The following application.properties with the `List<Test>` change:

```
engineal.x.value: "Test1"
engineal.x.test[0].value: "Test2"
engineal.x.test[0].test[0].value: "Test3"
```

will output `EnginealConfig{x=Test{value='Test1', test=[Test{value='Test2', test=[Test{value='Test3', test=null}]}]}}`. I can then access the next element by using `test.get(0)`.

So it appears as if recursion is supported only if the recursive type is in a collection.

While this workaround is ok, I would prefer to use my first way of doing it. Are/should recursive classes be supported without needing a collection? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I believe this might be solved by using a _custom converter_ (/w `@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding`) but SpringBoot 2.x currently ignores the annotated object and there is a related issue here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13285

Comment: [This post](https://www.sothawo.com/2015/06/using-spring-boot-configuration-properties-in-your-own-classes/) could help you, seems you need  `spring-configuration-metadata.json`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @LuisMuñoz, however, according to that article and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html, spring-configuration-metadata.json seems like it will only provide autocompletion in the IDE; and won't affect the actual config binding, which is where my issue lies. With that being mentioned, the spring-boot-configuration-processor throws a StackOverflowException with the example class I have provided, so it's apparent that it's unable to handle this recursive structure either.

Comment: Worth a bug report to Spring guys!

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16444

Comment: finally i got enough rep again to comment again^^ didn't really think about that when opening the bounty.

Basically I ran into the exact same problem and found no way around it. The docs neither mention allowing nor prohibiting recursion.

Thanks for opening the issue @engineAL!

Comment: Solution that you are trying to implement(Recursive approach) will introduce stackoverflow.Consider changing your design

Comment: At the moment it doesn't cause a stackoverflow exception, because Spring seems to specifially prohibit it. Which is probably because other injected beans would run into a stackoverflow exception, those injected beans don't have source data though. Since in this case the data structure of the source (the configuration) is final and it's depth limited, it shouldn't run into a stackoverflow exception. In my opinion there should be an annotation enabling us to allow recursive structures for bean injection at our own risk.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your inner class as an individual class, then everything would work well.

application.yml

```
simple:
  value: aa
  myTest:
    value: lower
```

config class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "simple")
@Data //It is for getter setter
public class SimpleConfig {

    private String value;

    private MyTest myTest;
}
```

the recursion class

```
@Data
public class MyTest {
    private String value;
    private MyTest myTest;
}
```

Test case

```
@Resource
private SimpleConfig simpleConfig;

@Test
public void myTest(){

    String value = simpleConfig.getValue();
    System.out.println("outerValue : " + value);
    String innerValue = simpleConfig.getMyTest().getValue();
    System.out.println("innerValue :" + innerValue);
}
```

result

```
outerValue : aa
innerValue :lower
```

Comment: That only works for the first layer though. If you add another layer (ie: simple.myTest.myTest.value, so there will actually be a recursion), Spring will detect the recursion and assign "null" to it.

Comment: Well "assigning null" is not exactly the correct way to say it, but I think you know what I mean.

Comment: yeah i just tried.it is like what you said.but I think I found a way to do this by rewrite something

Answer (score 0):

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "engineal")
public class EnginealConfig {

    static class Test {
        //@NestedConfigurationProperty
        private String value;

        @NestedConfigurationProperty
        private Test test;
```

You may annotate the field with `@NestedConfigurationProperty` annotation.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does not solve the issue. Adding `@NestedConfigurationProperty` to the field `EnginealConfig#Test.test` still results in the same exact configuration: `EnginealConfig{x=Test{value='Test1', test=null}}`

Comment: It is actually stated that "this annotation has no bearing on the actual binding processes" in the docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/NestedConfigurationProperty.html